# Incompatible pointer types returning 'NSArray * _Nonnull' from a function with result type 'ARArrayList *'

Tags: objective-c

I am working with code from another developer (who is no longer around), and trying to fix some warnings in the code they left.

I have managed to fix all errors and warnings except one, which is this...

```
Incompatible pointer types returning 'NSArray * _Nonnull' from a function with result type 'ARArrayList *'
```

Xcode points to the following block of code with this warning...

```
-(instancetype) split:(NSUInteger)numberOfPartitions
{
id result = [NSMutableArray new];
if (numberOfPartitions>0){
    NSUInteger i = 0;
    id subcollection = [[self class] emptyMutable];
    for (id object in self){
        [subcollection addObject:object];
        i++;
        if (i%numberOfPartitions==0) {
            [result addObject:subcollection];
            subcollection = [[self class] emptyMutable];
        } else if (i==[self count]){
            [result addObject:subcollection];
        }
    }
}
return [NSArray arrayWithArray:result];
}
```

And the sidebar in Xcode shows this...

[image]

Can anyone see how to fix this? This last warning is getting annoying!

Comment: Why is the return type declared as `instancetype` instead of `NSArray *`?

Comment: The code is not mine, and I am not an expert on coding, so I have no idea!

Comment: @rmaddy, you have the right answer. Can you leave that as an answer so it can be upvoted and accepted?

Comment: @uliwitness You need to read the comments below the accepted answer. The original answer stated the same thing as my comment. The updated answer you are commenting on is correct according to Richard. It doesn't make much sense to me but the OP seems to think it is correct and there isn't really enough information about this `ARArrayList` class to know for sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your class is `ARArrayList` so `instancetype` is `ARArrayList` not `NSArray`.

To get rid of the warning cast the return value to `ARArrayList`

```
(ARArrayList *)[result copy];
```

Comment: Changing to use that line changes the warning to "Method is expected to return an instance of its class type 'ARArrayList', but is declared to return 'NSArray *'"

Comment: Then revert the return type to `instancetype` and  try `return (instancetype)[result copy];`

Comment: Use of undeclared identifier 'instancetype'

Comment: Next attempt: `return (ARArrayList *)[result copy];`

Comment: @Richard Make the change mentioned in the answer but also update the corresponding declaration in the header file.

Comment: We have a winner! return (ARArrayList *)[result copy]; has fixed it and removed my final warning! Thank you!

Comment: The answer does not reflect the actual solution scattered through the comments. I would suggest updating the answer.

Comment: The answer is wrong. It hides the legitimate error, but it doesn't fix the issue. An ARArrayList is not an NSArray. This will blow up for you at runtime. Do what another commenter said and fix the actual issue, which is that the code declares the wrong return type.